# After update from Android 5 to 6 new permission model does not affect application

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow, htc, permissions

1. I had an application installed on HTC M8 Android 5.1, e.g. app was able to read `Contacts`.
2. Device was updated to Android 6.0.
3. I want to check how new permission model works so in app's settings I disable `Contacts`.
4. Then I go to app and try to read `Contacts` and ... **it works but AFAIK it should not**.
5. However I can't make phone calls from within the app (SecurityException happens).

Why is that?

Comment: Link the app here and mention the version you're using. It is possible that you're not using the updated version or the latest version isn't targeted at SDK 23, the reason why it is able to read contacts.

Comment: Yes it may be the case - can you please link to description of your statement and make it answer as it probably is the answer?

Comment: Can you please link the app and the version you're using. I don't think I was correct. Google noted [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html): "*Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level. You should test your app to verify that it behaves properly when it's missing a needed permission, regardless of what API level your app targets.*"

Comment: I can't because it's not released anywhere (I'm developing it right now).

Comment: OK, I see that I can only read Contast's name not the number, see details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572694/android-6-read-contacts-permission-allows-to-read-contact-name-when-permission-i